# KMS get_public_key() UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kms

When I run the following code (KEY_ID is a key_id that I've copied and pasted from the list returned from client.list_keys() ):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client("kms")
client.list_keys()
client.get_public_key(KeyId = "KEY_ID")

# I've also tried:
client.get_public_key(KeyId = "KEY_ID", GrantTokens = [])
```

I get the following error:

```
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.UnsupportedOperationException: An error occurred (UnsupportedOperationException) when calling the GetPublicKey operation:
```

Anyone know what parameters I'm missing for the get_public_key() method?

Answer (score 1):

[get_public_key](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.get_public_key) is only for [asymmetric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/symm-asymm-concepts.html#asymmetric-cmks) keys. These keys have **public** and **private** components.

Most KMS keys used at AWS are [symmetric](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/symm-asymm-concepts.html#symmetric-cmks), and these keys don't have any public component. Instead you would use **data key** obtained from [generate_data_key](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kms.html#KMS.Client.generate_data_key).